# SugarCRM: Webpage Link (accessible only by logged in users)

Tags: sugarcrm

I am currently using the MySites dashlet to link users to another webpage.  The problem is that anybody who knew the URL could access the same page (which has proprietary information on it).

I would like to create a link within SugarCRM to a webpage that is only accessible to users who are currently logged into the CRM.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Is-it un internal SugarCRM page? If yes you can use an entryPoint for that with "auth" params to true: http://support.sugarcrm.com/02_Documentation/04_Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.5/02_Application_Framework/Entry_Points/02_Creating_Custom_Entry_Points